# Updating issue for Drupal 9.0.3 to 9.0.6 using composer on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, drupal-9

Hi I'm trying to update a drupal install from 9.0.3 to 9.0.6 its throwing an exception during the composer update Its installed on Ubuntu 18.04

I've run

```
composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies
```

I'm getting the following output

````
PHP Warning:  Module 'apcu' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Cannot create cache directory /home/user/.composer/cache/repo/https---packages.drupal.org-8/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/user/.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/user/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 3 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.9 => v4.4.13):     Update failed (Could not delete /home/user/articles/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php: Module 'apcu' already loaded)
    Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? yes
  - Removing symfony/http-kernel (v4.4.9)

Does anyone know how to fix this?                                                                                                                                      
  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                  
  Could not delete /home/user/articles/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Profiler/FileProfilerStorage.php: Module 'apcu' already loaded  
                                                                                                                                      

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...```

I've tried 

`composer update drupal/core-recommended "symfony/*" --with-dependencies` to update the symfony packages as well which didn't work

I tried posting this on the Drupal support forums but they flag any new post as spam then delete it, good technique to keep the issues down :)

Thx for any help
````

Comment: Have you tried removing the `vendor` folder?

Comment: I've tried removing the vendor directory and it now shows
[RuntimeException]                                                              
  Could not delete libraries/codesnippet/plugin.js: Module 'apcu' already loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my composer commands need to be run as the root user
it complains that i shouldn't run as root but it only works correctly when I do

I've managed to update to Drupal 9.0.7 from 9.0.3 now running the standard command

```
sudo composer update drupal/core-recommended --with-dependencies

PHP Warning:  Module 'apcu' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating drupal/core (9.0.3 => 9.0.7): Downloading (100%)         
  - Updating drupal/core-recommended (9.0.3 => 9.0.7)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Hardening vendor directory with .htaccess and web.config files.
28 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
Cleaning vendor directory.
```